# Android. Animation on gravity change

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a FrameLayout within another one. It is aligned to the center.

No I want to align it to top by changing it gravity, but I also want to animate this change.

I already found this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33192335/408780, but LayoutTransition.CHANGING using there needs API 16.

Our app's however minSdk is 14. Any suggestions how to animate gravity change?

Thank you in advance

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/bg"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/container_bg"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add

```
compile 'com.android.support:transition:25.2.0'
```

to your app dependencies.
Then, add this line before change gravity (TransitionManager from android.support.transition package)

```
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(parentOfAnimatedView);
```

For example

```
mContainer.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) mContainer.getParent());
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mContainer.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        mContainer.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    });
```

Comment: Is there any callback for when the animation is complete?

Comment: Try this:
val transition = AutoTransition()
transition.addListener(object : TransitionListenerAdapter() {
    override fun onTransitionEnd(transition: Transition) {
        // your code
    }
})
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(parentOfAnimatedView, transition)